# What and how is the best way to implement message.properties using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I looked at jquery.i18n, but it caused quite a lot of issues in IE with my application which has to work in ie7+. I am using JavaScript MVC and i'm not sure they work too well together.

What i want to do is have a message.properties file with a bunch of keys and then replace the hard coded text in my html and js with the appropriate message property key.

I am looking for a plain javascript/jquery approach rather than a plugin. 
If anyone out there has done this or could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: _"but it caused quite a lot of issues in IE7"_ can you elaborate? This doesn't seem like a library where browser incompatibility is to be expected.

Comment: It fails to to get passed the script tag in the head of the html and also by the looks of it, there are currently a number of reported IE issues on the i!8n plugin site: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/issues/list